# Limit Heroku dyno one day a month

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a node app running on Heroku. I want my dyno to be active one day a month (all the day).
I have read the Heroku scheduler doc but it does not seems to allow that kind of job.

Is there a way to let my paid dyno active only one day a month automatically ? (first day of the month)

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a [custom clock process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes) on heroku. The docs are pretty terrible, here's a rough guide.

1. Create a `clock.js` file and set it up as you would your cron file. The `cron` npm package is nice.
2. Create a `Procfile` and just add the line `clock: node clock.js` to it, nothing else.
3. Deploy your app to heroku.
4. On your app dashboard, change the default dyno settings (resources tab at time of writing) from `web` to `clock`